# SQL Parser Disambiguation

Tags: parsing

I have written a very simple SQL Parser for a very small subset of the language to handle a one time specific problem. I had to translate an extremely large amount of old SQL expressions into an intermediate form that could then possibly be brought into a business rule system. The initial attempt worked for about 80% of the existing data.

I looked at some commercial solutions but thought I could do this pretty easy based on some past experience and some reading. I hit a problem and decided to go and finish the task with a commercial solution, I know when to admit defeat. However I am still curious as to how to handle this or what I may have done wrong.

My initial solution was based on a simple recursive descent parser, found in many books and online articles, producing an Abstract Syntax Tree and then during the analysis phase, I would determine type differences and whether logical expressions were being mixed with algebraic expressions and such.

I referenced the ANTLR SQL Lite grammar by Bark Kiers
https://github.com/bkiers/sqlite-parser

I also referenced an online SQL grammar site
http://savage.net.au/SQL/

**The main question is how to make the parser differentiate between the following**

expr AND expr

BETWEEN expr AND expr

The problem I am encountering is when I hit the following unit test case

**case when PP_ID between '009000' and '009999' then 'MA' when PP_ID between '001000' and '001999' then 'TL' else 'LA' end**

The '009000' and '009999' is matched as a Binary Expression so the parser throws an error expecting the keyword AND but instead encounters THEN.

The online ANSI grammar actually breaks down expressions into finer grained productions and I suspect that is the proper approach. I am also wondering if my parser should detect if an expression is actually Boolean vs. Algebraic during the parse phase and not the semantic phase, and use that information to handle the above case.

I am sure I could brute force the solution but I want to learn the correct way to handle this.

Thanks for any help offered.

Comment: What's your current grammar?

Comment: The above snippet is the only current ambiguity I am having, that it matches the AND as a binary expression and consumes it instead of just taking the '009000'.

Answer (score 1):

I also met with this problem while developed [Jison](http://zaach.github.io/jison/) (Bison) [parser for SQLite](https://github.com/agershun/WebSQLShim/blob/master/src/sqliteparser.jison), and solved it with who different rules in grammar for binary operations: one for AND and one for BETWEEN (this is a Jison grammar):

```
%left BETWEEN    // Here I defined that AND has higher priority over BETWEEN
%left AND        // 

: expr AND expr      // Rule for AND
    { $$ = {op: 'AND', left: $1, right: $3}; }
;
: expr BETWEEN expr   // Rule for BETWEEN
    { 
        if($3.op != 'AND') throw new Error('Wrong syntax of BETWEEN AND');
        $$ = {op: 'BETWEEN', expr: $1, left:$3.left, right:$3.right}; 
    }
;
```

and then parser checks right expression, and pass only expressions with AND operations. May be this approach can help you.

For ANTLR grammar I found the following rule (see [this grammar](https://github.com/agershun/WebSQLShim/blob/master/stuff/grammar/g4/SQLite.g4) made by Bart Kiers)

```
 expr
 :
 | expr K_AND expr
 | expr K_NOT? K_BETWEEN expr K_AND expr
 ;
```

But I am not sure, that it works in proper way.

Comment: What I have done so far to hold me over is during the Parse Phase, I check inside the AND rule to see if the left hand expression is logical or not. If it is not logical, I jump out of the AND match and it falls to the BETWEEN. 

So far it is working for all my test cases but it still feels wrong. In the online SQL-92 grammar, they break things down to a much finer level and I think this is the proper approach but given the limited scope of my problem compared to a full production SQL parser, I will go with my test for now until I find a better way.

Take care.